# Slick Slider. Slides twitch when switching

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slick.js

Когда выбираю следующий слайд, он сначала уходит немного влево, а потом становится нормально, по центру. Как можно избавиться от такого "дёрганья"?

Если убрать `variableWidth`, то этот эффект исчезает, но тогда не устраивает то, как отображается слайдер.

```js
$('.myWorks-wrapper').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  variableWidth: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
.my-works {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #0E066C;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.myWorks-wrapper{
    max-width: 1300px;
    height: 800px;
    display: flex;
}

.myWorks-element {
    width: 312px;
    height: 490px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #3728E4;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 50%;
    margin: 90px 30px;
}

.my-works .myWorks-wrapper .myWorks-element.slick-center .myWorks-el-top {
    width: 480px;
    height: 270px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 0px 0px;
}

.my-works .myWorks-wrapper .myWorks-element.slick-center .myWorks-el-bottom {
    width: 480px;
    height: 400px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.my-works .myWorks-element.slick-center {
    opacity: 100%;
    transition: all 0.7s;
    width: 480px;
    height: 690px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.my-works .myWorks-element.slick-center .myWorks-el-title {
    font-size: 36px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.my-works .myWorks-element.slick-center .myWorks-el-text {
    font-size: 32px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.my-works .myWorks-wrapper .myWorks-element.slick-center .myWorks-el-bottom .myWorks-el-link {
    width: 380px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    font-size: 32px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.myWorks-el-top {
    width: 312px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
    height: 193px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    background: url('../images/my-works-element-first.png');
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.myWorks-el-bottom {
    width: 312px;
    height: 275px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.myWorks-el-title {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Pacifico;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.myWorks-el-text {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: MontserratR;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}

.myWorks-el-link {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background: #CB2F51;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: MontserratEB;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<section class="my-works secJS">
            <div class="myWorks-wrapper">
                <div class="myWorks-element">
                   <div class="myWorks-el-top"></div>
                   <div class="myWorks-el-bottom">
                       <div class="myWorks-el-textes">
                           <div class="myWorks-el-title">Healthy Bite</div>
                           <div class="myWorks-el-text">Website, online health food store</div>
                       </div>
                       <a href="#" class="myWorks-el-link">check</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myWorks-element">
                    <div class="myWorks-el-top"></div>
                    <div class="myWorks-el-bottom">
                        <div class="myWorks-el-textes">
                            <div class="myWorks-el-title">Healthy Bite</div>
                            <div class="myWorks-el-text">Website, online health food store</div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="myWorks-el-link">check</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myWorks-element">
                    <div class="myWorks-el-top"></div>
                    <div class="myWorks-el-bottom">
                        <div class="myWorks-el-textes">
                            <div class="myWorks-el-title">Healthy Bite</div>
                            <div class="myWorks-el-text">Website, online health food store</div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="myWorks-el-link">check</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myWorks-element">
                    <div class="myWorks-el-top"></div>
                    <div class="myWorks-el-bottom">
                        <div class="myWorks-el-textes">
                            <div class="myWorks-el-title">Healthy Bite</div>
                            <div class="myWorks-el-text">Website, online health food store</div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="myWorks-el-link">check</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myWorks-element">
                    <div class="myWorks-el-top"></div>
                    <div class="myWorks-el-bottom">
                        <div class="myWorks-el-textes">
                            <div class="myWorks-el-title">Healthy Bite</div>
                            <div class="myWorks-el-text">Website, online health food store</div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="myWorks-el-link">check</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myWorks-element">
                    <div class="myWorks-el-top"></div>
                    <div class="myWorks-el-bottom">
                        <div class="myWorks-el-textes">
                            <div class="myWorks-el-title">Healthy Bite</div>
                            <div class="myWorks-el-text">Website, online health food store</div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="myWorks-el-link">check</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </section>
```